# Why does my for loop only remove a number once in my function?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

```
def onlyEvens(L):
    # TODO - your code goes here 
    for i in L:
        if i%2 != 0:
            L.remove(i)
        
    return L

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = onlyEvens ( [ 3,5,6,2,10,8] ) 
    print(result)
```

when in the funtion the loop only ilterates once i want it so that it'll remove all odd number like
3 and 5 but in the instants it only removes 3 and does get to 5

```
[6, 2, 10, 8]
```

Comment: the reason is while applying `remove` function after removing it actually shifts the indexes of the remaining elements... instead you should create a new list which can store even values..